# Upgrade by restoring back up

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, backup, restore

I am upgrading my ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10, and my question is, after upgrading ubuntu, if i make back up of 12.10 then install 12.04 again and then if i restore the backup, will 12.04 upgrade to 12.10?
please answer immediately,
thanks

Comment: Please, what do you mean by "backup" ? (what would include this backup ?)

Comment: i m saying that if i restore backup of ubuntu 12.10 in 12.04 will ubuntu 12.04 upgrade to 12.10?i will make backup of entire disk drive in which ubuntu 12.10 is installed.
please answer

Answer (score 0):

If you restore a Full-Backup of your system on a Bare-Metal you will have the identical system that you have backuped. If everything goes well, you will have a running ubuntu 12.10, but this is not an upgrade - it is deleteing or overwriting all existing files and replace them with you backup.

Not every Backup-Software is able to make a Bare-Metal-Restore.

Comment: which software will make a Bare-Metal-Restore?

Comment: Bacula could do that, but it is an enterprise software and a lot of work and configuration is needed to make a Bare-Metal-Restore. I don't think there is a software for the desktop which provides this function. The Restore is not a good way to make an upgrade. Maybe you should aks a new question with what you want to do and maybe somebody can tell you an easier or better way to do it.